# Merge two lists having different dimensionality

Tags: python

I have 2 different lists of data of different shape. I need to merge them into one.

List A is of (100 x 5) shape and List B is of (1 X 100) shape.

Sample example:

List A:

```
[
 [  1.  34.62365962  78.02469282  11.    78.      81.        ]
 [  1.  30.28671077  43.89499752  13.    17.      51.        ]
 [  1.  35.84740877  72.90219803  74.    74.      62.        ]
]
```

List B:

```
  [0 1 1]
```

what I'd want to achieve is data from List A and List B together as follows:

```
<----------------- List A data----------------------------> <##List B###>
[
     [  1.  34.62365962  78.02469282  11.    78.      81.       0   ]
     [  1.  30.28671077  43.89499752  13.    17.      51.       1   ]
     [  1.  35.84740877  72.90219803  74.    74.      62.       1   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a loop.

```
for i in range(0,100):
     A[i].append(B[i])
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[v1+[v2] for v1,v2 in zip(A,B)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply zip list a and b:

```
   ListA =[
     [  1.,  34.62365962,  78.02469282,  11.,    78.,   81.  ],
     [  1.,  30.28671077,  43.89499752,  13.,    17.,   51.  ],
     [  1.,  35.84740877,  72.90219803 , 74.,    74. ,  62.  ]
    ]

    ListB = [0, 1,1]

    print(list(list(a) for a in zip(ListA, ListB)))
```

Output:

```
[
 [1.0, 34.62365962, 78.02469282, 11.0, 78.0, 81.0,  0],
 [1.0, 30.28671077, 43.89499752, 13.0, 17.0, 51.0,  1], 
 [1.0, 35.84740877, 72.90219803, 74.0, 74.0, 62.0,  1]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

just loop it and append

```
for x in range(0,100):
 A[x].append(B[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple zip would do it:

```
>>> for a, b in zip(A, B):
...     a.append(b)
>>> print(A)
[[1.0, 34.62365962, 78.02469282, 11.0, 78.0, 81.0, 0],
 [1.0, 30.28671077, 43.89499752, 13.0, 17.0, 51.0, 1],
 [1.0, 35.84740877, 72.90219803, 74.0, 74.0, 62.0, 1]]
```